# Filtro para marcas HTML con AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Estoy creando una API usando [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) para mostrar ciertos textos en la vista, me aparecen las marcas de HTML.

Esta es mi plantilla:

```
<div class="well well-lg">
  <p class="lead">
    {$ policy.politica $}
  </p>
</div>
```

Y esto es lo que sale al visualizar la página:

```
...  nos comprometemos a <mark>garantizar el ejercicio de blah blah blah</mark> al ofrecer un ...
```

Puesto que estoy usando Bootstrap v3, esperaría ver el texto con fondo coloreado o algo similar en lugar de las etiquetas `<mark></mark>`. Entiendo que se debe el contenido debe *escaparse*, pero no sé como hacerlo en AngularJS.

Agradeceré su ayuda.

> **Nota:** Se están usando los delimitadores `{$ $}` para el binding de Angular por conveniencia porque en servidor se tiene Django que usa `{{ }}`

Comment: estas seguro que se trata de angular? porque el {$ ... $} eso no es angular, si lo fuera usaria {{ ... }}

Comment: Oh, estoy usando Django y cambien las marcas con `$interpolateProvider`. Gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: La etiqueta `django`no es relevante en la pregunta. El comportamiento de AngularJS se modifica desde la propia aplicación de Angular.

Comment: si es relevante porque django esta cambiando la notacion por defecto que usa angular y eso hay que aclararlo, por eso ambas etiquetas

Comment: No, no la cambia Django. Cambio la notación porque así me conviene, pero la cambio en Angular. No es el comportamiento normal, pero no Django no tiene nada que ver, mira: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider

Comment: ok pense que el cambio lo definias desde django

Comment: Es posible que el motor de plantillas de Django esté escapando la cadena en servidor ¿Como asignas el valor a la variable `policy.politica`?

Comment: Gracias @rsciriano, en realidad la respuesta de jjimenez es correcta. Necesito el servicio `$sce` que se encuentra en el módulo `ngSanitize`.

Comment: Pues si es la respuesta correcta, por favor, marcarla como tal para que sirva para el resto de usuarios. Por cierto, en [esta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25500347/1724791) respuesta de S.O. en ingles hay un ejemplo para hacer un filtro usando `$sce.trustAsHtml`, de esta manera sería mas cómodo de usar. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que esto es así como medida de seguridad, para evitar inyecciones de HTML malicioso. Dicho esto, si confías plenamente en ese código HTML, puedes hacerlo usando el servicio `$sce` de AngularJS [1].

Con esto:

```
$scope.myContent = $sce.trustAsHtml(someContent);
```

Y usando en la plantilla la directiva `ng-bind-html` así:

```
<div ng-bind-html="myContent"></div>
```

el contenido de `myContent`se renderizaría como HTML correctamente.

[1] https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Answer (score 3):

Como alternativa a la solución de [jjimenez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/5464/jjimenez) de usar `$sce.trustAsHtml` en el controlador se puede crear un filtro que permita usarlo directamente desde la plantilla.

El filtro sería así:

```
myApp.filter('rawHtml', ['$sce', function($sce){
  return function(val) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
  };
}]);
```

En tu plantilla lo usarías así:

```
<div class="well well-lg">
  <p class="lead">
    {$ policy.politica | rawHtml $}
  </p>
</div>
```